# Use of super class

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to follow an Android tutorial for [caching bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) and looking at the sample code confuses me.

The code defines some utility classes as ImageFetcher, ImageResizer, and ImageWorker. Fetcher extends Resizer and Resizer extends Worker.

When Fetcher is called in the tutorial it invokes this code.

```
public ImageFetcher(Context context, int imageSize) {
    super(context, imageSize);
    init(context);
}
```

The super class Resizer invokes this code

```
public ImageResizer(Context context, int imageSize) {
    super(context);
    setImageSize(imageSize);
}
```

And finally the super class Worker invokes this code

```
protected ImageWorker(Context context) {
    mResources = context.getResources();
}
```

What I don't understand is what resizing has to do with fetching, what working has to do with resizing, and why these classes are arranged like this. I'm trying to emulate something like this for my own app and was looking at what would be considered a good example but it only confused me further. I naively thought that you could simply have a class that does the fetching, not extended from one that did resizing (since they seem completely separate actions to me).

Yes I am new to Java as well.

Comment: *What I don't understand is what resizing has to do with fetching, what working has to do with resizing, and why these classes are arranged like this* Your question is not about Java super classes but how Google defined the framework to create Android applications.

Comment: *I naively thought that you could simply have a class that does the fetching, not extended from one that did resizing (since they seem completely separate actions to me)* and you're right, this is just a design matter. You can have your own `Resizer` class which needs a `Resizable` object to resize and no need to extend anything. You have to understand that there are no absolute rules in software design but **there are good practices** to follow, but none of these are **a must** to follow blindly.

Comment: Thanks @LuiggiMendoza. So the lesson here is that I shouldn't get too worried if things look a bit strange to begin with and that I don't have to follow those rules absolutely when building my own apps. Thanks again.